# Why is constructor being invoked?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Why is `s1()` constructor being invoked here?

```cpp
#include<iostream>

struct s1 {
    s1(int tmp) {

    }

    s1() {
        std::printf("s1 invoked");
    }
};

struct s2 {
    s1 s;
    s2(s1& s) {
        this->s = s;
    }
};
int main() {

    s1 o1(5);
    s2 o2(o1);
    return 0;
}
```

result:
`s1 invoked`

Why passing by reference in `s2(s1& s)` invokes `s1()` constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the implementation of `s2(s1&)`:

```
s2(s1& s) {
    this->s = s;
}
```

The data member `s` is default-initialized via the default constructor firstly, then gets assigned inside the constructor body.

You should initialize it directly in [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

```
s2(s1& s) : s(s) // direct-initialize data member s from parameter s
{}
```

Comment: @Ivan It won't make much difference with pass-by-reference, the point is how to initialize the data member `s`.

Answer (score 3):

Passing the `s1` from main does not default construct one. Having a member `s1` that does not appear in the member initialiser of `s2`'s constructor does.

It seems you want

```
struct s2 {
    s1 s;
    s2(s1& s) : s(s) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you did not initialize the `s` member at all. Of course, it cannot just be not constructed. So its default constructor is called implicitly.

Only *after* all members (and base classes) have been initialized (constructed), the body of the `s2` constructor (and the line `this->s = s`) gets executed. By then, the `s` member is already default-constructed. As the other answers suggest, You can avoid this by calling a constructor explicitly in a member-initializer list.